# Nested grid containers and items are not fitting in the screen using material UI react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a UI like below but for some reasons its not coming through as expected.

I have tried changing columns too but that didn't work either.

Problem is that I am using Grid and it contains respective items and containers but changing them screw up the complete design.

Here is my code:

```
<React.Fragment>
                <Container maxWidth="xl">
                    <Grid container spacing={1} className="mainBlock">
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <div className="rightBlock liproCard">
                                <Grid container spacing={1} style={{height: '115px'}}>
                                    <Grid item sm={2} style={{lineHeight: '2.5'}}>
                                        Jahr
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={3}>
                                        <TextField
                                            select
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            className="select-box"
                                            size="small"
                                            id="year"
                                            value={year}
                                            onChange={(e) => this.yearHandler(e)}>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2016'}>2016</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2017'}>2017</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2018'}>2018</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2019'}>2019</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2020'}>2020</MenuItem>
                                        </TextField>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={2} style={{lineHeight: '2.5'}}>
                                        Jahr
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={3}>
                                        <TextField
                                            select
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            className="select-box"
                                            size="small"
                                            id="year"
                                            value={year}
                                            onChange={(e) => this.yearHandler(e)}>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2016'}>2016</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2017'}>2017</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2018'}>2018</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2019'}>2019</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2020'}>2020</MenuItem>
                                        </TextField>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={2} style={{lineHeight: '2.5'}}>
                                        Jahr
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={3}>
                                        <TextField
                                            select
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            className="select-box"
                                            size="small"
                                            id="year"
                                            value={year}
                                            onChange={(e) => this.yearHandler(e)}>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2016'}>2016</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2017'}>2017</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2018'}>2018</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2019'}>2019</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2020'}>2020</MenuItem>
                                        </TextField>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={2} style={{lineHeight: '2.5'}}>
                                        Jahr
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={3}>
                                        <TextField
                                            select
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            className="select-box"
                                            size="small"
                                            id="year"
                                            value={year}
                                            onChange={(e) => this.yearHandler(e)}>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2016'}>2016</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2017'}>2017</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2018'}>2018</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2019'}>2019</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2020'}>2020</MenuItem>
                                        </TextField>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={2} style={{lineHeight: '2.5'}}>
                                        Jahr
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item sm={3}>
                                        <TextField
                                            select
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            className="select-box"
                                            size="small"
                                            id="year"
                                            value={year}
                                            onChange={(e) => this.yearHandler(e)}>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2016'}>2016</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2017'}>2017</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2018'}>2018</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2019'}>2019</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value={'2020'}>2020</MenuItem>
                                        </TextField>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>

                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
```

Here is current output:

[image]

Here is the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Material-ui's grid container](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) is a responsive layout system that is based on 12 columns. This means that inside every Grid Container - you can have at most 12 grid-items with `xs={1}`, 6 grid-items with `xs={2}`, 4 grid-items with `xs={3}` and so on.

you can also have combinations of the above, for example:

```
|        xs == 6        |  xs == 3  |  xs == 3  | 
  ^ This will get 50%      ^ 25%        ^ 25%
```

In your code the sum of items counts 20, which is more than 12 (the number of columns the grid supports).

You can either divide your columns differently, or not use the Grid structure (you can [move to tables](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) for example, if that makes more sense to you).